# How do I implement a pepper in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, security, spring-security

I was trying to make my Application secure, when I tought to myself that I should implement peppers, so that the password is secure. I haven't really found any solutions using the spring-security framework, so I wanted to ask if it's even possible.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Spring Security > Features > Authentication > Password Storage](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/authentication/password-storage.html)
, Spring Security provides a number of built-in ways to encode passwords in a password store.  Indeed, you can implement your own encoding scheme.

Looking at the existing `StandardPasswordEncoder` [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/StandardPasswordEncoder.html) we see that is described as combining the password, a salt and a secret in the input to a crypto hash function (SHA-256).  The secret can be "system wide" or specific to the encoder.  You could either use this class directly, or clone and modify it.

### **HOWEVER**

The `StandardPasswordEncoder` class has been deprecated by Spring.  According to them, the approach of hashing a salted password is insecure, even when you add a secret; e.g. a "pepper".

According to them, a more secure approach is to use a very computationally expensive (i.e. slow) function to do the hashing.  They provide a number of encoders that work this way; e.g. `BCryptPasswordEncoder`, `Argon2PasswordEncoder`, `Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder` and `SCryptPasswordEncoder`.

So my advice would be:

1. Do not use `StandardPasswordEncoder`.  It is deprecated.
2. Do not to try roll your own Spring password encoding scheme based on salts and peppers.  In addition to the systemic weakness of such schemes (which is why `StandardPasswordEncoder` is deprecated), you risk injecting extra weaknesses due to flaws in your own implementation; e.g. the handling of the "pepper" secret(s).
3. Do use one of the alternatives (see above) that the Spring engineers have developed, tested and support.